# weird Safari webfont letter spacing bug

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having some strange letter-spacing issues...

Safari:

[image: Safari]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

I've tried:

```
letter-spacing: 0.2em;
font-weight: 400;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;
line-height: 1.34em;
text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
font-feature-settings: "liga" 0;
font-variant-ligatures: none;
```

to no avail

Comment: Might help to know what font you're using. Or better yet, a StackSnippet or jsFiddle.